# Ошибка при попытке открыть COM порт JSSC

Tags: java, com-port, jssc

В Java новичек, прошу помощи знатоков. Пытаюсь сделать пересылку данных через COM порт с помощью библиотеки JSSC. Список портов получить удалось а вот при попытке открыть порт в консоль выдает следующее:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=51626:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath D:\Java_projects\SerialPortConnect\out\production\SerialPortConnect;D:\Java_projects\jSSC-2.7.0-Release\jssc.jar;D:\Java_projects\SerialPortConnect\lib\javafx.base.jar;D:\Java_projects\SerialPortConnect\lib\javafx-swt.jar;D:\Java_projects\SerialPortConnect\lib\javafx.fxml.jar;D:\Java_projects\SerialPortConnect\lib\javafx.media.jar;D:\Java_projects\SerialPortConnect\lib\javafx.web.jar;D:\Java_projects\SerialPortConnect\lib\javafx.controls.jar;D:\Java_projects\SerialPortConnect\lib\javafx.graphics.jar;D:\Java_projects\SerialPortConnect\lib\javafx.swing.jar Main
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006ec4b5bb, pid=2752, tid=6732
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (11.0.1+13) (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [jSSC-2.7_x86_64.dll+0xb5bb]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\Java_projects\SerialPortConnect\hs_err_pid2752.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

Process finished with exit code 1


#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000007110b5db, pid=7912, tid=3644
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (11.0.1+13) (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [jSSC-2.8_x86_64.dll+0xb5db]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=55221:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.2\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 Main

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-8130U CPU @ 2.20GHz, 4 cores, 11G,  Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 17763 (10.0.17763.292)
Time: Tue Feb 19 21:04:01 2019 RTZ 2 (ceia) elapsed time: 0 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000268793b1800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=3644, stack(0x0000008118000000,0x0000008118100000)]

Stack: [0x0000008118000000,0x0000008118100000],  sp=0x00000081180ff3e0,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [jSSC-2.8_x86_64.dll+0xb5db]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  jssc.SerialNativeInterface.openPort(Ljava/lang/String;Z)J+0
j  jssc.SerialPort.openPort()Z+65
j  Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+15
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

siginfo: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), reading address 0x0000000077391bf8


Register to memory mapping:

RIP=0x000000007110b5db jSSC-2.8_x86_64.dll
RAX=0x0000000077391bf8 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00000081180ff450 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000268793b1800
RCX=0x00007ffb801df854 ntdll.dll
RDX=0x0 is NULL
RSP=0x00000081180ff3e0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000268793b1800
RBP=0x00000081180ff560 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000268793b1800
RSI=0x00000268793b1b40 points into unknown readable memory
RDI=0x0000000000000454 is an unknown value
R8 =0x00000081180ff2d8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000268793b1800
R9 =0x00000081180ff3d0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000268793b1800
R10=0x0 is NULL
R11=0x0000000000000246 is an unknown value
R12=0x00000081180ff620 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000268793b1800
R13=0x000002687fe1c440 points into unknown readable memory
R14=0x00000081180ff510 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000268793b1800
R15=0x00000268793b1800 is a thread


Registers:
RAX=0x0000000077391bf8, RBX=0x00000081180ff450, RCX=0x00007ffb801df854, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x00000081180ff3e0, RBP=0x00000081180ff560, RSI=0x00000268793b1b40, RDI=0x0000000000000454
R8 =0x00000081180ff2d8, R9 =0x00000081180ff3d0, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x0000000000000246
R12=0x00000081180ff620, R13=0x000002687fe1c440, R14=0x00000081180ff510, R15=0x00000268793b1800
RIP=0x000000007110b5db, EFLAGS=0x000000000001020

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000081180ff3e0)
0x00000081180ff3e0:   00000081180ff408 0000008100000000
0x00000081180ff3f0:   000000007110b230 00007ffb8015267d
0x00000081180ff400:   00000081180ff620 0000000000000004
0x00000081180ff410:   00000268793b1b40 0000000000000454
0x00000081180ff420:   00000081180ff560 0000000071112590
0x00000081180ff430:   00000081180ff490 0000008100000000
0x00000081180ff440:   00000000c0000000 0000000000000000
0x00000081180ff450:   0000000000000454 00007ffb7c48f77c
0x00000081180ff460:   00000081180ff510 000002687fe1c440
0x00000081180ff470:   00000081180ff620 0000000000000454
0x00000081180ff480:   0000000071113500 0000000071113be8
0x00000081180ff490:   00000081180ff4c0 0000000071112641
0x00000081180ff4a0:   00000081180ff430 0000000000000000
0x00000081180ff4b0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00000081180ff4c0:   00000081180ff560 0000000071101595
0x00000081180ff4d0:   000000000000001c 0000026800000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000007110b5db)
0x000000007110b5bb:   c5 0f 1f 40 00 55 57 56 53 48 83 ec 28 48 8b 05
0x000000007110b5cb:   39 33 01 00 48 89 cb 48 85 c0 0f 84 c5 00 00 00
0x000000007110b5db:   8b 38 85 ff 0f 88 ab 00 00 00 48 8b 05 1c 33 01
0x000000007110b5eb:   00 48 85 c0 0f 84 bc 00 00 00 8b 30 85 f6 74 57 



---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Threads class SMR info:
_java_thread_list=0x000002687fdbf5f0, length=11, elements={
0x00000268793b1800, 0x000002687fb37800, 0x000002687fb69000, 0x000002687fbbc800,
0x000002687fbbf000, 0x000002687fbc1800, 0x000002687fbc5000, 0x000002687fc23800,
0x000002687fae7000, 0x000002687fe63800, 0x000002687fe64800
}

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x00000268793b1800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=3644, stack(0x0000008118000000,0x0000008118100000)]
  0x000002687fb37800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10468, stack(0x0000008118700000,0x0000008118800000)]
  0x000002687fb69000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3636, stack(0x0000008118800000,0x0000008118900000)]
  0x000002687fbbc800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8144, stack(0x0000008118900000,0x0000008118a00000)]
  0x000002687fbbf000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2528, stack(0x0000008118a00000,0x0000008118b00000)]
  0x000002687fbc1800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10984, stack(0x0000008118b00000,0x0000008118c00000)]
  0x000002687fbc5000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7056, stack(0x0000008118c00000,0x0000008118d00000)]
  0x000002687fc23800 JavaThread "Sweeper thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6324, stack(0x0000008118d00000,0x0000008118e00000)]
  0x000002687fae7000 JavaThread "Common-Cleaner" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1724, stack(0x0000008118e00000,0x0000008118f00000)]
  0x000002687fe63800 JavaThread "Monitor Ctrl-Break" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1376, stack(0x0000008118f00000,0x0000008119000000)]
  0x000002687fe64800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2276, stack(0x0000008119000000,0x0000008119100000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000002687fb31800 VMThread "VM Thread" [stack: 0x0000008118600000,0x0000008118700000] [id=1812]
  0x000002687fe68000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000008119100000,0x0000008119200000] [id=8812]
  0x00000268793c8800 GCTaskThread "GC Thread#0" [stack: 0x0000008118100000,0x0000008118200000] [id=10652]
  0x000002687940a000 ConcurrentGCThread "G1 Main Marker" [stack: 0x0000008118200000,0x0000008118300000] [id=7820]
  0x000002687940c000 ConcurrentGCThread "G1 Conc#0" [stack: 0x0000008118300000,0x0000008118400000] [id=8428]
  0x000002687947d800 ConcurrentGCThread "G1 Refine#0" [stack: 0x0000008118400000,0x0000008118500000] [id=2364]
  0x000002687947e800 ConcurrentGCThread "G1 Young RemSet Sampling" [stack: 0x0000008118500000,0x0000008118600000] [id=6200]

Threads with active compile tasks:

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap address: 0x0000000741e00000, size: 3042 MB, Compressed Oops mode: Zero based, Oop shift amount: 3
Narrow klass base: 0x0000000800000000, Narrow klass shift: 0
Compressed class space size: 1073741824 Address: 0x0000000800000000

Heap:
 garbage-first heap   total 196608K, used 2048K [0x0000000741e00000, 0x0000000800000000)
  region size 1024K, 3 young (3072K), 0 survivors (0K)
 Metaspace       used 6573K, capacity 6707K, committed 6784K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 581K, capacity 638K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
Heap Regions: E=young(eden), S=young(survivor), O=old, HS=humongous(starts), HC=humongous(continues), CS=collection set, F=free, A=archive, TAMS=top-at-mark-start (previous, next)
|   0|0x0000000741e00000, 0x0000000741e00000, 0x0000000741f00000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x0000000741e00000, 0x0000000741e00000| Untracked 
|   1|0x0000000741f00000, 0x0000000741f00000, 0x0000000742000000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x0000000741f00000, 0x0000000741f00000| Untracked 
|   2|0x0000000742000000, 0x0000000742000000, 0x0000000742100000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x0000000742000000, 0x0000000742000000| Untracked 
|   3|0x0000000742100000, 0x0000000742100000, 0x0000000742200000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x0000000742100000, 0x0000000742100000| Untracked 
|   4|0x0000000742200000, 0x0000000742200000, 0x0000000742300000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x0000000742200000, 0x0000000742200000| Untracked 
|   5|0x0000000742300000, 0x0000000742300000, 0x0000000742400000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x0000000742300000, 0x0000000742300000| Untracked 
|   6|0x0000000742400000, 0x0000000742400000, 0x0000000742500000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x0000000742400000, 0x0000000742400000| Untracked 
|   7|0x0000000742500000, 0x0000000742500000, 0x0000000742600000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x0000000742500000, 0x0000000742500000| Untracked 
|   8|0x0000000742600000, 0x0000000742600000, 0x0000000742700000|  0%| F|  
| 130|0x000000074a000000, 0x000000074a000000, 0x000000074a100000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x000000074a000000, 0x000000074a000000| Untracked 

| 174|0x000000074cc00000, 0x000000074cc00000, 0x000000074cd00000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x000000074cc00000, 0x000000074cc00000| Untracked 
| 175|0x000000074cd00000, 0x000000074cd00000, 0x000000074ce00000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x000000074cd00000, 0x000000074cd00000| Untracked 
| 176|0x000000074ce00000, 0x000000074ce00000, 0x000000074cf00000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x000000074ce00000, 0x000000074ce00000| Untracked 
| 177|0x000000074cf00000, 0x000000074cf00000, 0x000000074d000000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x000000074cf00000, 0x000000074cf00000| Untracked 
| 178|0x000000074d000000, 0x000000074d000000, 0x000000074d100000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x000000074d000000, 0x000000074d000000| Untracked 
| 179|0x000000074d100000, 0x000000074d100000, 0x000000074d200000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x000000074d100000, 0x000000074d100000| Untracked 
| 180|0x000000074d200000, 0x000000074d200000, 0x000000074d300000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x000000074d200000, 0x000000074d200000| Untracked 
| 181|0x000000074d300000, 0x000000074d300000, 0x000000074d400000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x000000074d300000, 0x000000074d300000| Untracked 
| 182|0x000000074d400000, 0x000000074d400000, 0x000000074d500000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x000000074d400000, 0x000000074d400000| Untracked 
| 183|0x000000074d500000, 0x000000074d500000, 0x000000074d600000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x000000074d500000, 0x000000074d500000| Untracked 
| 184|0x000000074d600000, 0x000000074d600000, 0x000000074d700000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x000000074d600000, 0x000000074d600000| Untracked 
| 185|0x000000074d700000, 0x000000074d700000, 0x000000074d800000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x000000074d700000, 0x000000074d700000| Untracked 
| 186|0x000000074d800000, 0x000000074d800000, 0x000000074d900000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x000000074d800000, 0x000000074d800000| Untracked 
| 187|0x000000074d900000, 0x000000074d900000, 0x000000074da00000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x000000074d900000, 0x000000074d900000| Untracked 
| 188|0x000000074da00000, 0x000000074da00000, 0x000000074db00000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x000000074da00000, 0x000000074da00000| Untracked 
| 189|0x000000074db00000, 0x000000074db91618, 0x000000074dc00000| 56%| E|  |TAMS 0x000000074db00000, 0x000000074db00000| Complete 
| 190|0x000000074dc00000, 0x000000074dd00000, 0x000000074dd00000|100%| E|CS|TAMS 0x000000074dc00000, 0x000000074dc00000| Complete 
| 191|0x000000074dd00000, 0x000000074de00000, 0x000000074de00000|100%| E|CS|TAMS 0x000000074dd00000, 0x000000074dd00000| Complete 

Card table byte_map: [0x0000026879a80000,0x000002687a080000] _byte_map_base: 0x0000026876071000

Marking Bits (Prev, Next): (CMBitMap*) 0x000002687735e7b8, (CMBitMap*) 0x000002687735e7f0
 Prev Bits: [0x000002687a680000, 0x000002687d608000)
 Next Bits: [0x0000026817250000, 0x000002681a1d8000)

Polling page: 0x0000026878b80000

Metaspace:

Usage:
  Non-class:      5.93 MB capacity,     5.85 MB ( 99%) used,    73.84 KB (  1%) free+waste,     3.75 KB ( <1%) overhead. 
      Class:    638.00 KB capacity,   581.91 KB ( 91%) used,    54.21 KB (  8%) free+waste,     1.88 KB ( <1%) overhead. 
       Both:      6.55 MB capacity,     6.42 MB ( 98%) used,   128.05 KB (  2%) free+waste,     5.63 KB ( <1%) overhead. 

Virtual space:
  Non-class space:        8.00 MB reserved,       6.00 MB ( 75%) committed 
      Class space:        1.00 GB reserved,     640.00 KB ( <1%) committed 
             Both:        1.01 GB reserved,       6.63 MB ( <1%) committed 

Chunk freelists:
   Non-Class:  1.38 KB
       Class:  256 bytes
        Both:  1.63 KB

CodeHeap 'non-profiled nmethods': size=120064Kb used=64Kb max_used=64Kb free=119999Kb
 bounds [0x000002680fd10000, 0x000002680ff80000, 0x0000026817250000]
CodeHeap 'profiled nmethods': size=120000Kb used=263Kb max_used=263Kb free=119736Kb
 bounds [0x00000268087e0000, 0x0000026808a50000, 0x000002680fd10000]
CodeHeap 'non-nmethods': size=5696Kb used=1062Kb max_used=1069Kb free=4633Kb
 bounds [0x0000026808250000, 0x00000268084c0000, 0x00000268087e0000]
 total_blobs=624 nmethods=211 adapters=256
 compilation: enabled
              stopped_count=0, restarted_count=0
 full_count=0

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 0.217 Thread 0x000002687fbc5000  205       3       sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser::isInvalidPathChar (22 bytes)
Event: 0.218 Thread 0x000002687fbc5000 nmethod 205 0x000002680881f310 code [0x000002680881f500, 0x000002680881f890]
Event: 0.219 Thread 0x000002687fbc5000  206       3       jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe::putObjectRelease (9 bytes)
Event: 0.219 Thread 0x000002687fbc5000 nmethod 206 0x000002680881fa10 code [0x000002680881fbc0, 0x000002680881fd78]
Event: 0.219 Thread 0x000002687fbc5000  208       3       java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder::newCapacity (55 bytes)
Event: 0.219 Thread 0x000002687fbc5000 nmethod 208 0x000002680881fe10 code [0x000002680881ffe0, 0x0000026808820270]
Event: 0.219 Thread 0x000002687fbc5000  209       3       java.lang.StringLatin1::replace (196 bytes)
Event: 0.220 Thread 0x000002687fbc5000 nmethod 209 0x0000026808820390 code [0x0000026808820600, 0x0000026808821300]
Event: 0.222 Thread 0x000002687fbc5000  211       3       java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source::hashN (26 bytes)
Event: 0.222 Thread 0x000002687fbc5000 nmethod 211 0x0000026808821790 code [0x0000026808821940, 0x0000026808821b78]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (1 events):
Event: 0.169 Thread 0x00000268793b1800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000002680fd1ca88 method=java.util.HashMap.putVal(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 69 c2

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (0 events):
No events

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.224 loading class java/net/Proxy$Type
Event: 0.224 loading class java/net/Proxy$Type done
Event: 0.224 loading class sun/net/spi/DefaultProxySelector$1
Event: 0.224 loading class sun/net/spi/DefaultProxySelector$1 done
Event: 0.224 loading class sun/net/NetProperties
Event: 0.224 loading class sun/net/NetProperties done
Event: 0.224 loading class sun/net/NetProperties$1
Event: 0.224 loading class sun/net/NetProperties$1 done
Event: 0.225 loading class java/util/Properties$LineReader
Event: 0.225 loading class java/util/Properties$LineReader done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff6a7f80000 - 0x00007ff6a7fc7000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\java.exe
0x00007ffb80140000 - 0x00007ffb8032d000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ffb65b90000 - 0x00007ffb65ba2000     C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\aswhook.dll
0x00007ffb7f360000 - 0x00007ffb7f413000     C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ffb7c460000 - 0x00007ffb7c6f3000     C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ffb7d910000 - 0x00007ffb7d9b3000     C:\Windows\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ffb7ff40000 - 0x00007ffb7ffde000     C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ffb7f9d0000 - 0x00007ffb7fa6e000     C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll
0x00007ffb7f420000 - 0x00007ffb7f542000     C:\Windows\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ffb7dc70000 - 0x00007ffb7de07000     C:\Windows\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007ffb7c800000 - 0x00007ffb7c820000     C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007ffb7fa70000 - 0x00007ffb7fa99000     C:\Windows\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ffb7c210000 - 0x00007ffb7c3aa000     C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007ffb7c700000 - 0x00007ffb7c7a0000     C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x00007ffb7d150000 - 0x00007ffb7d24c000     C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007ffb614b0000 - 0x00007ffb61729000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.17763.316_none_05b53be2071f46b6\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007ffb7f5c0000 - 0x00007ffb7f8ed000     C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll
0x00007ffb7d2d0000 - 0x00007ffb7d34e000     C:\Windows\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ffb77da0000 - 0x00007ffb77daa000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ffb7d9c0000 - 0x00007ffb7d9ee000     C:\Windows\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x00007ffb68740000 - 0x00007ffb68756000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\vcruntime140.dll
0x00007ffb5a500000 - 0x00007ffb5a5aa000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\msvcp140.dll
0x00007ffb3f670000 - 0x00007ffb401b2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ffb7fd40000 - 0x00007ffb7fd48000     C:\Windows\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ffb71f60000 - 0x00007ffb71f69000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ffb7f550000 - 0x00007ffb7f5bd000     C:\Windows\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ffb73310000 - 0x00007ffb73334000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ffb730d0000 - 0x00007ffb730fd000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007ffb7d250000 - 0x00007ffb7d29a000     C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x00007ffb7c140000 - 0x00007ffb7c151000     C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ffb67460000 - 0x00007ffb67471000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\verify.dll
0x00007ffb75ea0000 - 0x00007ffb7608d000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DBGHELP.DLL
0x00007ffb75b80000 - 0x00007ffb75baa000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbgcore.DLL
0x00007ffb5c0a0000 - 0x00007ffb5c0c9000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\java.dll
0x00007ffb5a6d0000 - 0x00007ffb5a6ff000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\instrument.dll
0x00007ffb65bf0000 - 0x00007ffb65c06000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\zip.dll
0x00007ffb77640000 - 0x00007ffb7764a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\jimage.dll
0x00007ffb7de10000 - 0x00007ffb7f2ff000     C:\Windows\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ffb7d370000 - 0x00007ffb7d418000     C:\Windows\System32\shcore.dll
0x00007ffb7c820000 - 0x00007ffb7cf6a000     C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll
0x00007ffb7c1e0000 - 0x00007ffb7c204000     C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll
0x00007ffb7c180000 - 0x00007ffb7c1dd000     C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll
0x00007ffb7d8a0000 - 0x00007ffb7d8f2000     C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll
0x00007ffb7d350000 - 0x00007ffb7d367000     C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll
0x00007ffb62c00000 - 0x00007ffb62c19000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\net.dll
0x00007ffb73b20000 - 0x00007ffb73c11000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINHTTP.dll
0x00007ffb7b9d0000 - 0x00007ffb7ba37000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x00007ffb61430000 - 0x00007ffb61443000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\nio.dll
0x00007ffb5d830000 - 0x00007ffb5d84a000     C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.2\bin\breakgen64.dll
0x0000000071100000 - 0x0000000071125000     C:\Users\spo12\.jssc\windows\jSSC-2.8_x86_64.dll

dbghelp: loaded successfully - version: 4.0.5 - missing functions: none
symbol engine: initialized successfully - sym options: 0x614 - pdb path: .;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin;C:\Windows\SYSTEM32;C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast;C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.17763.316_none_05b53be2071f46b6;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\server;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.2\bin;C:\Users\spo12\.jssc\windows

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=55221:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.2\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
java_command: Main
java_class_path (initial): D:\Java_projects\Serial_jSSC\out\production\Serial_jSSC;D:\Java_projects\jssc.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

[Global flags]
     intx CICompilerCount                          = 3                                         {product} {ergonomic}
     uint ConcGCThreads                            = 1                                         {product} {ergonomic}
     uint G1ConcRefinementThreads                  = 4                                         {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t G1HeapRegionSize                         = 1048576                                   {product} {ergonomic}
    uintx GCDrainStackTargetSize                   = 64                                        {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t InitialHeapSize                          = 201326592                                 {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t MarkStackSize                            = 4194304                                   {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 3189768192                                {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t MaxNewSize                               = 1913651200                                {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t MinHeapDeltaBytes                        = 1048576                                   {product} {ergonomic}
    uintx NonNMethodCodeHeapSize                   = 5830092                                {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx NonProfiledCodeHeapSize                  = 122914074                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx ProfiledCodeHeapSize                     = 122914074                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx ReservedCodeCacheSize                    = 251658240                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
     bool SegmentedCodeCache                       = true                                      {product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseCompressedClassPointers               = true                                 {lp64_product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseCompressedOops                        = true                                 {lp64_product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseG1GC                                  = true                                      {product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseLargePagesIndividualAllocation        = false                                  {pd product} {ergonomic}

Logging:
Log output configuration:
 #0: stdout all=warning uptime,level,tags
 #1: stderr all=off uptime,level,tags

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin;;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;D:\Programs\PuTTY\;C:\Users\spo12\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
USERNAME=Влад
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 17763 (10.0.17763.292)

CPU:total 4 (initial active 4) (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 142 stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2, adx, fma

Memory: 4k page, system-wide physical 12163M (6760M free)
TotalPageFile size 14019M (AvailPageFile size 6768M)
current process WorkingSet (physical memory assigned to process): 39M, peak: 39M
current process commit charge ("private bytes"): 265M, peak: 265M

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.1+13-LTS) for windows-amd64 JRE (11.0.1+13-LTS), built on Oct  6 2018 13:20:16 by "mach5one" with MS VC++ 15.5 (VS2017)

END.
```

Comment: jvm упала, в hs_err_pid2752.log стектрейс , приложите его

Comment: я сейчас посмотрел, последний коммит на гитхаб в эту либу в 2013 году, попробуте для проверки взять актуальную на то время jvm а не 11

Comment: Подскажите, как  здесь приложить файл?

Comment: или в текст вопроса или ссылкой на какой-нибудь pastebin

Comment: Добавил за исключением вот таких вот повторяющихся строк | 174|0x000000074cc00000, 0x000000074cc00000, 0x000000074cd00000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x000000074cc00000, 0x000000074cc00000| Untracked 
| 175|0x000000074cd00000, 0x000000074cd00000, 0x000000074ce00000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x000000074cd00000, 0x000000074cd00000| Untracked 
| 176|0x000000074ce00000, 0x000000074ce00000, 0x000000074cf00000|  0%| F|  |TAMS 0x000000074ce00000, 0x000000074ce00000| Untracked

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Загвоздка была в версии JDK. dll - ки написаны под 8-ую версию, а стояла 11. При откате к более старой все заработало